# Return pointer to array or make void function with parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

Till now most of the time I was using functions that return pointer to array, but now I started using void function with reference to array, so I am wondering which one of below code is better to use and why?

```
void doSomething(int** &ary)
{
    ary = new int*[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        ary[i] = new int[3];
    ary[0][0] = 1;
    ary[0][1] = 2;
}

int** ary=NULL;
doSomething(ary);
```

or this

```
int** doSomething1()
{
    int **ary = new int*[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        ary[i] = new int[3];
    ary[0][0] = 1;
    ary[0][1] = 2;
    return ary;
}

int **ary1=doSomething1();
```

Comment: It is a matter of opinion. The second version is less awful than the first one.

Comment: And what would be better?

Comment: Use a type that represents whatever it is you are trying to return. A pointer to a pointer can mean too many things.

Comment: Neither is better, return a `std::vector` until you have a real reason to do otherwise. Then, switch to C++ 11 move semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of opinion, however, here is mine:

I think the version that returns the pointer is better. Why? Simply because it makes the calling site less magic. With the return variant, you call the function like this:

```
int** my2dArray = doSomething();
```

It is perfectly clear, that `my2dArray` is initialized to point to some array that the function supplies. *Without a single look at the function definition.*

On the other hand, the call

```
int** my2dArray;
doSomething(my2dArray);
```

should always ring an alarm bell for the reader: It looks as if you are passing an uninitialized pointer to the function. Even after looking up the function definition, and seeing that the pointer is passed by reference, a reader still can't be certain that the function does not interpret the value that is passed in. It requires a close look at the code to make sure that this call is indeed legitimate.

So, for the sake of debugability, I avoid passing reference arguments. I pass by value, I pass by `const` reference (which has the same semantic as pass by value), or I pass by explicit pointer. That way no function call can modify a value that is not explicitly visible at the calling site.

Comment: What about memory leak or performance? Maybe any other better option?

Comment: To prevent memory leaks, you should use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr<>` and `std::shared_ptr`, or similar). In terms of performance you need to worry that your objects are not copied needlessly, something you can easily achieve by passing by const reference. Pass by reference and pass by explicit pointer are equivalent with respect to performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no big difference between the two examples, however I'd prefer the second example.

In the first example, you take a reference to `ary`, which means your program has to dereference all pointers each time it accesses an element somewhere in `ary`. (A reference is equivalent to a pointer after the code has been compiled)

In the second example, you only need to copy the pointer when the function returns.

**First example:**

reference to pointer to array -> pointer to array -> element in array

**Second example:**

pointer to array -> element in array